# launchd job not on list, but still running

Tags: macos, mac, process, launchd

I have a launchd job that is running every two minutes, but it is not on the `sudo launchctl list`.

I was changing the plist file, both the name of the file, and the Label key. I didn't unload it before hand but loaded the newly named file. Maybe that is what caused this but I'd still expect it in the list.

But it is never on the `sudo launchctl list` list. I checked `cron` as good measure too.

I've checked the other users. I see the script that the launchd job runs every two minutes when I do `ps aux`. Is there a way I can use `ps aux` to see which launchd process spawned it?

What else can I do to stop this thing? Restarting the server has to be a last resort, as would restarting launchd but if that's the only option that's the only option.

There's this question too, but no one answered it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240550/weird-launchd-behaviour-process-still-running-after-deleting-launchd-file-and-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can use `ps aux` to see which launchd process spawned it?

If you use `ps -ef`, the first 3 entries on each line tell you the UID, PID and Parent PID of a process. Here's an example:

```
$  ps -ef|head -2
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0     1     0   0 30May16 ??        25:05.63 /sbin/launchd
```

Between these three, you should be able to figure out the source of the process you're looking for. Here's a rather obvious example where I'm looking at `softwareupdated` (the daemon for `softwareupdate`):

First I look for the process and then confirm it using `ps -ef <some_PID>`. I've gotten into the habit of ending searches with `grep -v grep` to exclude grep from my results

```
$  ps -ef|grep softwareupdated|grep -v grep
  200  3711     1   0 30May16 ??         6:45.49 /System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated
$  ps -ef 3711
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  200  3711     1   0 30May16 ??         6:45.49 /System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated
```

The parent PID is numbered `1` so I check that:

```
$  ps -ef 1
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0     1     0   0 30May16 ??        25:08.24 /sbin/launchd
```

Comment: nice! Worked like a charm. And it turned out it was under another user - I had assumed that `sudo launchctl list` would show all, but it is per user. Live and learn. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worked for me.  I loaded a job once under my username, once under root.  So it ran twice and I couldn't figure out why.